# asyctask with json and image processing

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm currently having no luck with sussing out how to process an image after I have pulled a url out as async only allows for one return does anyone have any suggestions?

```
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting song information

        try {
               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
               JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
               JSONObject arrayElement_0 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
               uname = arrayElement_0.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
               ptitle = arrayElement_0.getString(TAG_PROFILETITLE);
               age = arrayElement_0.getString(TAG_AGE);
               gender = arrayElement_0.getString(TAG_GENDER);
               status = arrayElement_0.getString(TAG_STATUS);
               small = arrayElement_0.getString(TAG_SMALL);

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(small).getContent());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Class that can hold both the Bitmap and the rest of the data? Though keeping the Bitmap in a class is a bad idea (they use a lot of memory). It's better to handle Bitmaps separately, in general.

Comment: do you happen to have an example in regards to this or a previous stackoverflow link ?

Comment: Hmm there's a few libraries that I've seen, though I don't use one personally. Here's one: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return multiple things, simply return an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example for anyone else struggling on how to do this hope this helps :)
http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/